# Error on magento installation

Tags: magento-1.9, php, apache

I need to set a magento website on local computer. While loading the website on local computer the page is not loading. This is the apache log.

```
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.551700 2017] [negotiation:error] [pid 8462] 
[client 127.0.0.1:38922] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: $
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871522 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCode() on boolean in /v$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871549 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871561 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/stage.elb2b.online/index.php:0
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871570 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   2. Mage::run() /var/www/stage.elb2b.online/index.php:71
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871578 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /var/www/stage.elb2b.online/app/Ma$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871587 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /var/www/stage.$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871596 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match() /var/www$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871604 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch() /var/www/stage$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871612 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   7. Mage_Install_IndexController->preDispatch() /var/www/stage.el$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871621 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   8. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch() /var/www/st$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871628 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP   9. Mage::dispatchEvent() /var/www/stage.elb2b.online/app/code/co$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871637 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  10. Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent() /var/www/stage.elb2b.onl$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871644 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  11. Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod() /var/www/stage.elb$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871653 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  12. MageWorx_CurrencySwitcher_Model_Observer->currencyAutoswitch($
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871660 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  13. MageWorx_GeoIP_Model_Geoip->getCurrentLocation() /var/www/sta$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871668 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  14. Mage::getSingleton() /var/www/stage.elb2b.online/app/code/loc$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871675 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  15. Mage::getModel() /var/www/stage.elb2b.online/app/Mage.php:477
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871683 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  16. Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance() /var/www/stage.elb$
[Tue Dec 26 23:25:23.871691 2017] [:error] [pid 8462] [client 127.0.0.1:38922] PHP  17. Mage_Customer_Model_Session->__construct() /var/www/stage.elb$
```

Can you please suggest how can I solve the problem. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your Apache Httpd.conf

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

If this don't help show me print of your php.info